# Parse a json array object in Redshift and convert to table

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to parse this JSON array and convert it into a table and do this in AWS Redshift?

This array:

```
 [
  {"Event":"start","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"process","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"end","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
 ]
```

Convert to a table with Event and EventDateTime fields.

I have tried the available json functions and string functions and have come up empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use the COPY command? What problem did you face?

Comment: I used the COPY command to load a full json file into a table and that array above went into a field, now I am trying to parse that data out using Redshift's available functionality, but coming up short. RS's json functions aren't helpful for this particular array. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You can now use Python UDF's with Redshift, so your SQL should be a lot more flexible now. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/user-defined-functions-for-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 5):

To perform a Redshift COPY from JSON Format, you must prepare a JSON data structure. [The JSON data structure is made up of a set of objects or arrays.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html)

In your example:

1. Create following data set and upload it to S3:

   ```
   {"event":"start","eventdatetime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
   {"event":"process","eventdatetime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
   {"event":"end","eventdatetime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
   ```
2. Create table on your cluster

   ```
   CREATE TABLE events (event VARCHAR, eventdatetime TIMESTAMP);
   ```
3. Run the COPY command

   ```
   COPY events FROM 's3://bucket/file' JSON 'auto' TIMEFORMAT 'auto' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=???;aws_secret_access_key=???';
   ```
4. Test the result

   ```
   SELECT * FROM events;
   ```

   [image: result]

*Please, keep in mind that in this example will use 'auto' mapping feature, and because [column names are always lowercase, matching field names must also be lowercase.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json).
If it's not an option, you can overcome this limitation using a [JSONPaths file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-from-json-examples-using-jsonpaths).*

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy command to load the table up in Redshift, use the following for reference,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

What is the problem you are facing when using the copy command, in my experience it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue relates to the square brackets surrounding the json documents, if you're able to remove those with pre-processing, you'll be able to use the copy command to get what you need.